# SQL Server - how to get meter of STDistance() or STLength()?

Tags: sql-server

How to get meter of `STDistance()` or `STLength()`?

I use

```
linestring(x y z, x y z, x y z, ...).STLength() //
point(x y).STDistance(point(x y))
```

but object has 0 of SRID...can I get meter length?

Comment: Welcome! Which coordinate system are you using for x y z ?

Comment: yes i use x y z

Comment: which units are you using ?

Comment: the metric system(cm, m, km...)

Comment: Are you using the `geometry` or `geography` data type? For the former, it's up to you to know what units your coordinates are expressed in. For the latter, the SRID has a native unit of length (which you can look up in `sys.spatial_reference_systems`).